# Updating custom lookup value from controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have been struggling with this problem for awhile and appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this

In my ORDERS I have added a custom field "ClassTeacher_c", this is a custom lookup field which looks at CONTACTS which are type = Teacher.

In my Visualforce page, I have a table of orders displayed with the dropdown box of all the teachers available. The user of this page would assign a teacher to an order by selecting the teacher in the dropdown and then clicking the save link. I also have a inputtext box to record the wage that the teacher would be paid.

The problem I am facing is when I click save the teacher cannot be saved to the order even though the wage is saved correctly. Also the debug log I added to help track the issue is not longer displayed. This is strange because I know the code is being run because I can correctly save the wage.

Visualforce:

```
<table id="classes" class="ordertable">

                    <tr id="{!o.OrderNumber}" class="tableheaderRow" >
                        <th rowspan="2"><button class="tbutton" value="{!o.OrderNumber}" onClick="return false">+</button></th>
                        <th> Class Id </th>
                        <th> Account Name </th>
                        <th> Programme </th>
                        <th> Programme Code </th>
                        <th> Class Start Date </th>
                        <th> Class End Date </th>
                        <th> Class Amount </th>
                        <th> Status </th>
                        <th> Teacher </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> Teacher Wage </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr> 

                    <tr id="test" class="tabledataRow" >   
                        <td>  <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.id}">{!o.OrderNumber}</apex:outputLink> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.AccountId}"/>  </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.Programme__r.Name}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.Programme_Code__c}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.EffectiveDate}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.EndDate}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.Total_Cost_Of_Class__c}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.Status}"/> </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.ClassTeacher__c}" /></td>


                        <td> <apex:selectList value="{!o.ClassTeacher__c}" size="1"> 
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllTeachers}" /> 
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </td>
                        <td> <apex:outputField value="{!o.Teacher_Wage__c}"/> </td>      
                        <td> <apex:inputText value="{!o.Teacher_Wage__c}"/> </td>

                        <td> 
                            <apex:commandLink action="{!saveClass}" value="save" onclick="return true">
                                <apex:param name="saveOrder" value="{!o.id}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  
                </table>
```

APEX

```
public with sharing class AllOrderController {

    List<OrderItem> aorderresults;
    Contact teacher; 

    public AllOrderController() {
        aorders = [
            SELECT Id, OrderNumber, AccountId, EffectiveDate , EndDate, Status, Total_Cost_Of_Class__c,
            ClassTeacher__r.Name, Teacher_Wage__c, Programme__r.Name, Programme_Code__c, ClassTeacher__r.Id, 
            ClassTeacher__c
            FROM Order
            order by OrderNumber desc];
    }
 public String selectedVal{get;set;}  

    public List<SelectOption > getAllTeachers(){     
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add( new SelectOption('0000','Choose Teacher'));
        for( Contact teacher : [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Type__c = 'Teacher' order by Id desc] ) {
            options.add( new SelectOption(teacher.Id,teacher.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

public void saveClass() {
        string oid = ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('saveOrder'); 
        Order singleRec = new Order();
        for (Order x: aorders) {
            if (oid == x.id) {
                singleRec = x;
                break;              
            }
        }
        if (singleRec != null)
             System.debug('order ' +singleRec);
            System.debug('order number ' +singleRec.OrderNumber);
            System.debug('TEACHER WAGE ' +singleRec.Teacher_Wage__c);
            System.debug('TEACHER ' +singleRec.ClassTeacher__c);
        update singleRec;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to set the Teacher Lookup field using the **"value"** option to a **teacher.Id** taken from the incoming select option:

```
<td> <apex:selectList value="{!o.ClassTeacher__c}" size="1"> 
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!AllTeachers}" /> 
     </apex:selectList>
</td>
```

Salesforce requires you to only use the data type of **String** when using the value option. You are trying to set it to a data type of **Id**. This may be your issue. Here is the documentation from Salesforce regarding the value option:

> A merge field that references the controller class variable that is
>   associated with this selectList. For example, if the name of the
>   associated variable in the controller class is myListSelections, use
>   value="{!myListSelections}" to reference the variable. If multiselect
>   is true, the value attribute must be of type String[] or a List of
>   strings. Otherwise, it must be of type String.